# How do I alternate DIV colors in a while loop?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Let's say I have a code that looks like this:

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_p)) {
    $name = stripslashes($info['name']);
    $desc = stripslashes($info['description']);
    $desc = substr($desc, 0, 150);
    $price = stripslashes($info['price']);
    Print "<div style=\"width:600px; height:150px; border:1px solid black; overflow:hidden\"><div style=\"height:148px; width:25%; border:1px solid red; float:left\"><center><img src=\"".$picture."\" height=\"120\" width=\"120\" style=\"margin-top:15px\" /></center></div><div style=\"height:150px; width:50%; border:1px solid blue; float:left; text-overflow: ellipsis; padding-top:5px\"><center><font size=\"+1\"><b><a href=\"result.php?product=".urlencode($name)."\">".$name."</b></a></font><br><br>".$desc."...</center></div><div style=\"height:150px; width:24%; border:1px solid green; float:left\"><center><h1>$".$price."</h1><button>Add to Cart</button></center></div></div>";
```

The main DIV that is first defined in the while loop I would like to alternate two shades of grey. So in the results it would look like light dark light dark etc...I've tried simply repeating the echos again with a different color but that makes duplicates of each result.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would have a variable outside of the while loop keeping track of this. Then within the loop, you can say `$color = !$color` or something similar to toggle back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

```
$c = 1;

while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_p)) {
    $name = stripslashes($info['name']);
    $desc = stripslashes($info['description']);
    $desc = substr($desc, 0, 150);
    $price = stripslashes($info['price']);
    Print "<div style=\"background:" . ($c ? '#ccc' : '#aaa') . "width:600px; height:150px; border:1px solid black; overflow:hidden\"><div style=\"height:148px; width:25%; border:1px solid red; float:left\"><center><img src=\"".$picture."\" height=\"120\" width=\"120\" style=\"margin-top:15px\" /></center></div><div style=\"height:150px; width:50%; border:1px solid blue; float:left; text-overflow: ellipsis; padding-top:5px\"><center><font size=\"+1\"><b><a href=\"result.php?product=".urlencode($name)."\">".$name."</b></a></font><br><br>".$desc."...</center></div><div style=\"height:150px; width:24%; border:1px solid green; float:left\"><center><h1>$".$price."</h1><button>Add to Cart</button></center></div></div>";

    $c = 1 - $c;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your design and logic separated, you can do it with css as well:

```
div:nth-child(odd) {
   background:#c0c0c0;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
   background:#a0a0a0;
}
```

Comment: @user2566387 This is the professional-grade answer.  Don't muddy your php code assigning styles.  Use the elegance of css as it is intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can count amount of DIVs and change color on odd and even.

```
$num = 0;
while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_p)) {
 $num++;
 $color = ($num % 2) ? '#ccc;' : '#aaa';
//***insert your relevant variables
}
```